# How to hide <trace> in Magento REST API xml response?

Tags: rest-api

**Magento CE-1.9.2.4**

I am trying to use the **REST API** and when accessing (for example) http://my-domain.com/api/rest/customers the response is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<magento_api>
  <messages>
    <error>
      <data_item>
        <code>403</code>
        <message>Access denied</message>
        <trace>#0 /var/www/html/my-domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php(106): Mage_Api2_Model_Server-&gt;_allow(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request), Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Auth_User_Guest))
#1 /var/www/html/my-domain.com/api.php(73): Mage_Api2_Model_Server-&gt;run()
#2 {main}</trace>
      </data_item>
    </error>
  </messages>
</magento_api>
```

which is good, I mean the message is **Access denied**.

Is there a way **not to print** (hide) the `<trace>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

you get a trace in your REST API return error if your store is set to developermode (Magento 1.9.x). So you probably have something like this in your index.php file:

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
```

In a live environment no trace will be send along with the error message.

But just in case you want to hide the trace in your developer mode store in, for instance, a custom REST API function, you could for instance add this:

```
protected function _create($orderline)
...
if (!$results['success']) {
  Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false);
  return $this->_critical($results['message'], $results['code']);
  Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
...
```

Sometimes a bit handy when you want to develop but the rest api consumer should not be able to see the trace... So remove the setIsDeveloperMode lines in a live environment :-)